Ensuring std::cin doesn't allow non-integer input
The problem arises from the std::cin's weird behavior of treating std::uint8_t and std::int8_t as char-like types so it allows the input to be a character instead of a number and std::cin doesn't fail in such cases which is the wrong semantic behavior since I'm expecting a number from the input and not a character literal.
Hence I thought I should query the common type of std::uint16_t and T value and use it as the type of temp_value for getting input. I chose std::uint16_t simply because it's the smallest integral type that std::cin doesn't treat as a char type.
This probably makes sure that temp_value can never be of type std::uint8_t or std::int8_t and cause the aforementioned bug.
Is this the correct way to implement it?
I tried this:
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

// common type of std::uint16_t and std::uint8_t is int (surprisingly!)
static_assert( std::same_as<std::common_type_t<std::uint16_t, std::uint8_t>, int> );

int main( )
{
    std::uint8_t value;
    std::common_type_t<std::uint16_t, decltype( value )> temp_value; // int

    if ( std::cin >> temp_value &&
         std::in_range<decltype( value )>( temp_value ) )
    {
        value = temp_value;
        std::cout << static_cast<std::uint64_t>( value ) << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed" << '\n';
    }

}

For example, when the input is -1 or 256 the program prints Failed.
Is this correct and sufficient?

This will silently pass/fail on input like 1.5.  The 1 will be taken in as the value of the input and then the .5 will be left in the buffer.  I always advise that you use std::string and std::getline to read in the entire input line, then you can parse, validate and convert from there.

@NathanOliver Yes, good point. But I'm already using std::getline in my actual program to get the whole line and then pass it to a std::ispanstream for formatted extraction. I did not show it here for the sake of simplicity.

if you already have the characters extracted you can use std::isdigit to check they are digits

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I think it's not an ideal solution since it would be a waste in cases where value is not of type std::uint8_t. I mean in such cases std::cin would already fail when taking characters instead of digits. The problem only arises when value is an unsigned char, std::int8_t, etc.

"I mean in such cases std::cin would already fail when taking characters instead of digits" sorry, I think you misunderstand. I was refering to what Nathan said and that you said you are already reading whole lines (as std::string i suppose). Once you got that you can std::isdigit to check if a character is a digit or not. There is no waste, because if you going to extract somethign that can be a non-digit then you dont check

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah, I see. However, I prefer to rely only on operator>> and std::in_range for error detection (once I have the initial string).

This approach would still accept 1.5 as valid input, producing the value 1. Is this what you want? It's difficult to say whether the code is "correct" since you don't fully specifiy the problem it's supposed to solve.

@IgorTandetnik No it's not valid input. I don't want anything other than white space being left in the stream. I mean a ispanstream. I am currently using std::ws to discard the white space and then checking the eof() to determine whether it has hit the end or not.
